# Re-Ordering the Months By Federal Fiscal Year

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When running the following query I am trying to find a way to display the returned months by federal fiscal year instead of normal sequential value.

(ie I want to display months in the following order Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept instead of Jan thru Dec.) Thanks

```
select wrkgrp,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as January,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as February,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as March,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as April,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as May,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as June,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as July,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as August,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as September,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as October,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as November,
    sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as December,
from workorder
where reportdate between to_date ('2014-10-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
and   to_date ('2015-09-30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
and   wrkgrp = 'PublicWorks'
group by 'wrkgrp;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add case statements in your order by clause to get the desired sort.

```html
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN extract(month from reportdate) = 10 THEN 1 
CASE WHEN extract(month from reportdate) = 11 THEN 2 
ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields will display in your results (horizontally) in the order you list them in your select statement. Structure your statement with Oct listed first like this:

```
select wrkgrp,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as October,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as November,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as December,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as January,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as February,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as March,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as April,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as May,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as June,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as July,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as August,
sum (case when extract(month from reportdate) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as September
from workorder
where reportdate between to_date ('2014-10-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') ad to_date ('2015-09-30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') and
wrkgrp = 'PublicWorks'
group by 'wrkgrp;'
```